# ¿Como limitar un intervalo de 7 dias jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-datepicker

Tengo el siguiente codigo, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo limitar para que la fecha solo sea de 7 dias hacia atras o 7 dias hacia enfrente?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#fecha1').datepicker({
     startDate: '2015-12-01',
     format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
   });


  $('#fecha1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
    fInicial = getFormattedDate('fecha1');
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
  });

  $('#fecha2').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
    fFinal = getFormattedDate('fecha2');
    $(this).datepicker('hide');


    var jqxhr = $.post({
        url: 'assets/lib/infos.php',
        data: {
               inicio: fInicial,
               fin: fFinal
             },
        dataType: "JSON"
      })
      .done(function(json) {

        //codigo


      })
  });

});
```

asi como en este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Segun la documentacion en [jqueryui](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

**maxDate**

> The maximum selectable date. When set to null, there is no maximum.
>   Multiple types supported:
>
> - **Date**: A date object containing the maximum  date.
> - **Number**: A number of days from today. For example `2` represents two days from today and `-1` represents yesterday.
> - **String**: A string in the format defined by the *dateFormat* option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs;
>     valid periods are `"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, and
>     `"d"` for days. For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents one month and seven
>     days from today.

O en español:

> La máxima fecha seleccionable. Cuando es null, no hay máximo.
>   Multiples tipos soportados:
>
> - **Date**: Un objeto date conteniendo el valor de fecha máxima.
> - **Number**: Un número de días a partir de hoy. Por ejemplo `2` representa dos días a partir de hoy y `-1` representa ayer.
> - **String**: Un string en el formato definido por la opcion *dateFormat*, o una fecha relativa. Las fechas relativas deben contener pares de valor y periodo;
>     los periodos validos son `"y"` para años, `"m"` para meses, `"w"` para semanas, y
>     `"d"` para días. Por ejemplo, `"+1m +7d"` representa un mes y siete
>     días a partir de hoy.

En otras palabras tienes 2 opciones sencillas:

- Utilizando el formato de string relativo:

  ```
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    minDate: "-7d",
    maxDate: "+7d"
  });
  ```
- Utilizando el numero de días:

  ```
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    minDate: -7,
    maxDate: 7
  });
  ```

**Ejemplo:**

```js
$(function(){
  $(".myDate").datepicker({ minDate: -7, maxDate: 7 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<input type="text" class="myDate">
```

Comment: me interesa mucho tu respuesta, sin embargo no me funciona.`$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        todayBtn: "linked",
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        language: 'es',
        disableTouchKeyboard: false,
        minDate: -7,
        maxDate: 7
    });`

Comment: @C47 he agregado un snippet de ejemplo, tal vez te sea de ayuda

Comment: muy amable, esta excelente!

Answer (score 0):

Si estas empleando https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker, puedes jugar con las opciones del constructor, pasandole una fecha inicial y una final en dependencia del rango que deseas crear. Si pasas una cadena de string con el formato +<numero>d (**Ejemplo:** +2d) le sumará 2 días a la fecha inicial, si no la has definido es la fecha actual y si tiene la forma -<numero>d (**Ejemplo:** a-3d), le restará tantos días hayas indicado, en este caso 3.

**PARA QUE SEA los ultimos 7 dias hasta hoy**

```
$('#fecha1').datepicker({
 startDate: '-7d',
 endDate: '0d'
 format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

**PARA QUE SEA los próximos 7 dias incluyendo hoy**

```
$('#fecha1').datepicker({
 startDate: new Date(),
 endDate: '+7d'
 format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```